# statistics problem concerning probability, standard deviation, and mean

Tags: statistics

Keeneland is a popular horse racing track outside of Lexington that happens to have several drive-thru betting windows for people who would like to place wagers on races without entering the grandstand area. Suppose the mean time it takes an employee at one of these betting windows to serve a customer is 71 seconds, and this time is exponentially distributed.
a. Determine the rate parameter. [10 points] 
b. Determine the probability that someone will have to wait more than
100 seconds for the car in front of them to finish. [15 points]

I have no idea how to find either a or b

Comment: For Part A, what do we mean by "rate parameter" when we're talking about exponential distributions?  For Part B, since the support of an exponential distribution is $x > 0$, you need to find $P(X > 100)$; in other words, $\int_{100}^{\infty} f(x) dx$, where $f(x)$ is the p.d.f. (Of course, there may be a way to set up the integral so that you don't have to deal with infinity...)

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Rate Parameter  = $\lambda = 1/Meantime = 1/71 = 0.0140845$

f(x) = $\lambda*e^{-\lambda*x}$

$P(X>100) = 1-P(X<=100) = 1- \int_0^{100} \lambda*e^{-\lambda*x}dx=1+e^{-\lambda*x}$ ( evaluated for 100 and 0)

$$1+e^{-\lambda*100} -e^{0} = e^{-100/71} = 0.244522$$